# Consequence of First Homomorphism Theorem?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-homomorphism

Let $\phi:G\to\bar G$ be a surjective group homomorphism with kernel $N$. Then the first homomorphism theorem tells us that $G/N\cong\bar G$.

My question is this: Lagrange's theorem also tells us that $\frac{|G|}{|N|}=|\bar G|$ or $|G|=|\bar G||N|$ when $G$ is finite. Is it true that every element of $\bar G$ has exactly $|N|$ pre-images in $G$ under $\phi$?

For example, the identity of $\bar G$, call it $e_{\bar G}$, clearly has $|N|$ pre-images since $N$ is the kernel. We could say

$$\phi^{-1}(\{e_{\bar G}\})=N$$

Can always say that, if $\bar g\in \bar G$, then $|\phi^{-1}(\{\bar g\})|=|N|$

I'm still in my first semester of algebra, so keep it simple if possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first isomorphism theorem indicates elements $\bar{g}\in\overline{G}$ have fibers $gN\in G/N$ (a fiber is the preimage of a single element). Note that if two different $g$s in $G$ represent the same $\bar{g}$ in $\overline{G}$, then they represent the same coset $gN$ in $G/N$ (and vice-versa), so this is sensible to say.

Every coset $gN$ of $N$ has the same size as $N$. Indeed for any coset $gN$ (with choice of representative $g$) there is an simple bijection $N\to gN$ given by $n\mapsto gn$.

Comment: cool. so $\phi(gn)=\phi(g)$ so $gN$ must be in the fiber of $\phi(g)$. Then you could use contradiction to show that an element of $g'N$ where $g'$ is not in $gN$ cannot map to $\phi(g)$

Answer (score 2):

The preimage of an element is a double coset of $N$. Specifically, 
$$\phi^{-1}(\phi(a))=NaN$$
So every element of the preimage is of the form $nan'$ for $n,n'\in N$. However, $N$ is normal, so since
$$nan'=a(a^{-1}na)n'$$
this double coset is also a left (and right) coset of $N$. So the preimage of an element $\phi(a)$ is $aN$ and hence has exactly $N$ elements.

(It is actually a bit more complicated than this; $\phi^{-1}(\phi(a))=\{n_1a_1n_2a_2\cdots n_ka_kn_{k+1}:n_1,\ldots,n_{k+1}\in N,\ a_1a_2\cdots a_k=a\}$, but by the same argument this is just the same left coset.)

Comment: If $g_1$ and $g_2$ are sent to $\bar{g}$, then $g_1^{-1}g_2\in N$ (the kernel), so $g_1^{-1}g_2=n\Rightarrow g_2=g_1n$ for some $n\in N$. And conversely. Thus, every element looks like $g_1n$ for some $n\in N$, and the full preimage is $g_1N$ (which one may check is also $g_2N$ of course). Since there's this easy argument to make, as all the textbooks surely do, I am not sure what use there is in remarking on superficially alternate forms elements could look like, except as a perhaps tangential remark about quotient groups being well-defined.

Comment: @whacka I'm sorry you disapprove of my answer, but I stand by it.

Comment: (I said I don't understand the reasons behind the choice of form the elements of the preimage are taking, not that I "disapprove.")

Comment: @whacka Initially I was just going to write that it's the left coset, but I realized that if you were to naively try to take the preimage it would really have the form in my parenthetical remark. I figured this was worth mentioning.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, every element of $G$ looks like $n_1a_1\cdots n_k a_k n_{k+1}$ for some choice of $n_1,\cdots,n_{k+1}\in N$ and other elements $a_1,\cdots,a_k$ (Fact 1). Given that fact, in order for it to be sent to $\phi(a)$ by the homomorphism, we may conclude that $a_1a_2\cdots a_k=a$ must hold true (Fact 2). If that is your line of reasoning, it seems to me that proving Facts 1 & 2 here isn't more efficient or incisive than the textbook argument sketched in my first comment. Although I do recognize the importance of exploring elements' forms and images concretely like that.